# Boost + Python + Numpy = SIGSEGV

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, boost, boost-python

I'm currently getting started with Python (Version 3.5). For a current project, I wanted to include some C code (used for simulation) by writing a wrapper to this function with Boost-Python. Since results from this simulator will be used for computation with NumPy, I wanted to support NumPy Arrays in the C-Code.

The wrapper which I wrote actually works fine, however when the Python interpreter is terminated after the script execution, SIGSEGVs do sometimes occur. I tried looking into how Boost-Python handles memory ownership but I could not find a useful source of information for my problem.

Because of this I wanted to ask whether someone has an idea why those SIGSEGVs keep occurring. The relevant code for this problem is as follows:

setup.py (I'm building the project with python setup.py install)

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import os
import sys

source_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
dummy = Extension('dummypackage.dummy',
                  [os.path.join(source_path, "dummy.cpp")],
                  include_dirs=[source_path],
                  library_dirs=['/'],
                  libraries=['boost_python'],
                  extra_compile_args=['-g', '-Wno-return-type'])

setup(
    name="Dummy Project",
    version="1.0",
    install_requirements=[
        "numpy",
    ],
    ext_modules=[dummy],
)
```

dummy.cpp

```
#include "dummy.h"

#include "math.h"
#define SQ(x) ((x)*(x))

namespace mlpmp {

    using namespace boost::python;

    // Helper function for ND Array conversion
    object to_ndarray(double* data, int nd, npy_intp* size){
        PyObject *object = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(nd, size, NPY_DOUBLE, data);
        handle<> handle(object);
        numeric::array array(handle);

        return array.copy();
    }

    dict Foo::func(dict val){

        //Extract the arguments from the python dictionaries    
        numeric::array a = extract<numeric::array>(val["a"]);
        numeric::array b = extract<numeric::array>(val["b"]);

        double out_val[2];
        //... do some computations with the arrays and store them in out_val

        npy_intp size = 2;

        dict res;
        res["a"] = a.copy();
        res["b"] = b.copy();
        res["res"] = to_ndarray(out_val, 1, &size);

        return res;
    }
}
```

dummy.h

```
#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL dummy
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

#include <boost/python.hpp>

void* init_numpy(){
    import_array()
}

namespace mlpmp {

    using namespace boost::python;

    class Foo {
        public:
            static dict func(dict val);
    };

    BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(dummy){
        init_numpy();
        numeric::array::set_module_and_type("numpy", "ndarray");

        class_<Foo>("Foo")
            .def("func", &Foo::func)
            .staticmethod("func");
    }

}
```

Interestingly, it also suffices to only access the "val" dictionary with the "extract" functions to cause the SIGSEGVs. I checked this by just returning an empty array but still accessing the data. If I return an empty array and do not access the "val" dictionary, everything works fine.

One thing to mention at the end, the SIGSEGVs do not occur in every run, but (in my case) every third to fourth - so if you want to verify the problem you need to repeat if a few times.

If someone could help me out, this would be great

Best,
Pascal

Comment: Your 'init_numpy()' seems wrong at first glance. I think import_array() is not guaranteed to return anything; in that case, you have no defined return value.